# I keep getting a permission error when trying to update a site's template in liferay 7.3

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7

I've encountered an issue when trying to update a site's(group) template. The template is assigned and works correctly but a couple errors are thrown when doing so. They all read the same thing:

```
2023-01-18 10:42:24.934 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-48][FragmentRendererControllerImpl:120] Unable to render content of fragment entry 0:com.liferay.fragment.exception.FragmentEntryContentException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Someone may be trying to circumvent the permission checker: {company>
2023-01-18 10:42:24.936 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-48][FragmentRendererControllerImpl:120] Unable to render content of fragment entry 0:com.liferay.fragment.exception.FragmentEntryContentException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

this is not an error i understand. As i'm not checking for permission, someone without permission simply wouldn't see the button and couldn't press it. I have code for that in my view.jsp, but even when i remove it the error still persist.

This is the code i have for updating a group:

```
// I first update a custom field showing if the site is active or not
group.getExpandoBridge().setAttribute("Status", "Actief" );

LayoutSetLocalServiceUtil.updateLayoutSetPrototypeLinkEnabled(groupId, true, true, privateTemp);
```

Like I said I tried removing any permission checking code but this had no effect. The method i'm using is from the LayoutSetLocalServiceUtil class. Given that it's a local this method shouldn't check for permission either. I'm also logged in as admin when I try to run my code so I should have the permission to do this anyway.

I also tried to hide the error using:

```
SessionMessages.add(portletRequest, PortalUtil.getPortletId(portletRequest) + SessionMessages.KEY_SUFFIX_HIDE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

But this didn't actually hide it for some reason and it doesn't solve the issue either. Did anyone encounter this before? And why do i keep getting a permission error without checking any permission?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar permissions issues during the execution of custom code that updated ExpandoBridge attributes.  Try the following update:

```
boolean isSecure = false; // Forces the use of ExpandoBridgeLocalService w/o permissions checking
// I first update a custom field showing if the site is active or not
group.getExpandoBridge().setAttribute("Status", "Actief", isSecure);

LayoutSetLocalServiceUtil.updateLayoutSetPrototypeLinkEnabled(groupId, true, true, privateTemp);
```

Reference:
https://docs.liferay.com/dxp/portal/7.4-latest/javadocs/portal-kernel/com/liferay/expando/kernel/model/ExpandoBridge.html#setAttribute-java.lang.String-java.io.Serializable-boolean-